# Singular vs. plural verb form for an and-compound subject

Tags: verbs, singular-vs-plural

If the subject is an and-compound like "cat and dog", then some languages put the verb into the plural form:

> The cat and the dog **are** hungry.

Other languages take the quantity of the last element in the and-compound:

> The cat and the dog **is** hungry.
>
> The cat and all dogs **are** hungry.

What's the rule in English?

I came across this [sentence](https://angular.io/guide/elements#mapping):

> Component properties and logic maps directly into HTML attributes and the browser's event system.

suggesting the "quantity of the last element"-rule.

Comment: In general a subject with the form of a coordination of NPs linked by _and_ takes a plural verb, as in "The cat and the dog are hungry" /  "Mary and John are here". It doesn't matter whether the individual coordinates are singular or plural: the coordination as a whole denotes a set containing at least two members, and hence takes a plural verb. Singular override is possible where the subject is conceptualised as a single unit, e.g. "Eggs and bacon is my favourite breakfast".  In your last example, are "components and logic" seen as a single unit?

Comment: @BillJ Thx for the explanation. Yes, "components and logic" seem to be seen as as a single unit although there is no explicit grammar hint like a singular object in your example ("favourite breakfast").

Comment: Sometimes both are possible. e.g. "[Your laziness and your ineptitude] amazes/amaze me".

Comment: @BillJ Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The cat and the dog is / **are** hungry.*

In general a subject with the form of a coordination of NPs linked by *and* takes a plural verb. It doesn't matter whether the individual coordinates are singular or plural: the coordination as a whole denotes a set containing at least two members, and hence takes a plural verb.

Singular override is possible, though, where the subject is conceptualised as a single unit, e.g. [*Eggs and bacon*] ***is*** my favourite breakfast.

In your last example, it seems the writer's choice of the singular verb "maps" means that "components and logic" was intended to be conceptualised as a single unit, though it may just be an error, of course -- who knows?